# Не исполняется JS код собранный Webpack

Tags: javascript, django, webpack

Для начала вот мой конфиг сборки

```
const MiniCss = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
let path = require('path');

const base = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        app: "./static_src/base/js/base.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'base.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/base/js"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCss.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /.(gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
                use: "url-loader?limit=100000"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCss({
            filename: '../css/base.css',
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = [
    base
]
```

Сам входной файл `base.js`

```
import '../sass/base.scss';
import '../sass/additional.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import "./sidebar";
```

Файл `sidebar.js`

```
console.log("HELLO");
...
```

И структура `static_src`

[image: структура папок]

В базовом шаблоне такое подключение в статики

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base/css/base.css' %}">
    <scrpt src="{% static 'base/js/base.js' %}"></scrpt>
    ...
</head>
```

Вебпак всё собирает, стили подключаюся, а в исходном коде подключенного `base.js` можно увидеть нужный `eval("console.log(\"HELLO\");...` из `sidebar.js`

**Но код не выполняется**

Почему я не получаю лог?

Пробовал делать и консоль лог и алерт, пробовал подключать в `<body>`, пробовал подключать как `defer`, как `type="module"`. Так же каждый раз очищаю кеш и перезапускаю сервер. `CSP`,`CORS`,`FP` отключены.

Всё без толку, код то я получаю, а исполняться он не хочет. Код в `sidebar.js` заведомо верный и работал до того, как я начал собирать вебпаком

Answer (score 0):

Это входной файл.

```
//Компилируется, но не работает.
!function () {
    document.onload = function () {
        alert("Привет, Василий!");
        console.log("Привет, Василий!");
    };    
}();

//Компилируется и работает.
!function () {
    alert("Привет, Василий!");
    console.log("Привет, Василий!");
}();
```